# Can't set return type of a sql function to my class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an MVC app which uses linq to sql. I just imported a function from the database to my dbml file. I also added a class that I want to use as a return type for this function. However when I look through the dropdown list for return types (in the designer), my new class is not there (but various other classes are). Just to make sure, I closed and reopened the dbml file and restarted VS, but I still can't see my new class available as an option for the return type.

What is causing the behaviour and how do I make the function return the correct type on the C# end?

Note, my new class is in a separate cs file, but is placed in the same project and namespace as the dbml file.

Comment: Did you try compiling the project first?

Comment: @RonBeyer I did. I even rebuild it for good measure (and then the whole solution), but my new class does not show up. I also made sure I declared the class as public. I also tried changing all the properties to nullable and moving the class to the cs of the dbml file, but neither made any difference.

Comment: Can you post the function and the class you want to use?

Comment: Could it be that a sql function in linq to sql can only return an object (other than autogenerated) if it's of a class declared in the dbml file (from imported table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. To be able to use a class as a return type of a sql function, the class has to be added directly in the dbml file (maybe it has something with the mapping). If the class is declared elsewhere (even if it's the cs file of the dbml file) it won't work.

So in the end I had to move my class to the dbml file (recreate it in the designer).

---

Additionally linq to sql was quite picky about the column types returned by the function. I overcame that by looking through the types in the autogenerated return class. So why not go with the autogenerated class, you might ask? I had 3 sql functions that I needed to return the same output type, so autogenerated types were no good.